# How to cast string to list in PHP or MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a list of ids I want to fetch data from a Database.

```
$ids = "1,2,3,4";
```

Here is my query

```
$this->Execute("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id in (?)",array($ids));
```

This only gives my result where id=1. How do I fetch data where id is from 1 to 4?

Comment: Your query should already be doing this, assuming you actually have data where `id` is 1, 2, 3, or 4.

Comment: You need bind each of the ids using loop etc eg ... in (?,?,?,?)", array(1,2,3,4))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `FIND_IN_SET` since `$ids` is a string

```
$this->Execute("SELECT * FROM table WHERE FIND_IN_SET(id, ?)", array($ids));
```